# Unity Mesh and Collider not aligned on rotation

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes

I have a GameObject with a mesh and a collider. When I rotate the object the mesh and the colider do not act the same way and when the GameObject is rotate 65 degrees on the z axis the mesh and the colider are no longer aligned. This must affect game play. I don't understand why this happens and how it is supposed to be fixed.

Comment: What type of collider?

Comment: Its a Cube  Mesh with a Box  Collider

Answer (score 3):

I got it! 
The problem was that the GameObject that was not aligned with its colider was a child of another GameObject and that parent was scaled. When you dont have the scales (1,1,1) weird things happens to the children.

Solution is to create a root GameObject that never is scaled and then put children in it.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box this doesn't happen in my experience. I suggest to check if rotating it in design view has the same problem to rule out scripting effects. Most likely something is referencing the mesh and/or collider individually rather than just the GameObject.